The steel in the roof has rusted and the plaster is falling off. What can i do to protect the entire roof to fall off
Last year I found water leaking on my roof and the steel inside the concrete is rusting and hence cracks appearing in the roof. I removed all the plastering painted the now exposed steel with water proof paint. And plastered it up.  Now it is happening again after a year. How can I stop this. Is there a permanent solution to this problem.

Moving sounds good.  You probably want local eyes on site.  An engineer or building contractor.  Small pieces of concrete falling hurts your head.  Bigger pieces and a hardhat will not help.

This sounds like a structural issue.  You would be best served to contact a general contractor or engineer to determine what has been damaged and what needs to be done to correct it.  Asking internet people is not the solution.

Photos would help, but I  agree with @RMDman.
